# better search results for view taxonomy terms

Tags: views

A view with a taxonomy term field doesn't let you configure 'contains' like you can using title or body.
Using "one of" as the alternative, a "first-name second-name" entry does not show results when searching on "second-name first-name". Which is a pain.

[image: Title and body let you:]

[image: Taxonomy terms don't]

Searching for "Bobby Brown" will show results, "Brown Bobby" will not
Does any one know a solution?